# Connect Visual studio with database on server

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a free server (somee.com).

Now I'm trying to connect to that database from Visual Studio, I have to enter 'Server Name' when I press 'Add connection' .

Which Server Name should I fill there?

thanks!

Comment: it should be provided by somee.com , you should be able to see it in your CP

Comment: It looks like somee.com is a hosting provider. You will be connecting over the internet just like using SQL Azure.  Make sure that no firewalls are in place between your desktop (VS2010) and (SOMEE.COM).  A good way to test is ping.  Next, place the fully qualified address in the server line and pass the standard SQL credentials.  http://craftydba.com/?p=4827 (this is how to connect to sql azure via SSMS).

Comment: I believe you can contact your hosting provider. Basically every provider will tell about the conection string that you should use or you may find it on the CP.